# Response model as list of strings instead of objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to return a list of items in FastAPI via a Pydantic model.

Currently I have the route:

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

...

@router.get('/search-job-types', response_model=List[JobTypeDisplay])
def job_types(search_word: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
  return db_dims.search_job_types(search_word, db)

#db_dims:
def search_job_types(search_word: str, db: Session):
  s_word = search_word.capitalize()
  s_word2 = "%{}%".format(s_word)
  all = db.query(DbJobType).filter(DbJobType.name.like(s_word2)).all()
  #list_jobs = []
  #for item in all:
    #list_jobs.append(item.name)

  return all
```

And my schema is as the following:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class JobTypeDisplay(BaseModel):
  name: str
  class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I am getting a list of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Something3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Somethin2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Something1"
  }
]
```

But would like something like this:

```
['Something3', 'Somethin2', 'Something1']
```

What is the best way to achieve this and do I really need a loop for it?

Comment: Just as a side note, [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) is a built-in function in Python. It is considered bad form to shadow a name of a built-in function in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **only** interested in the values of the `name` column in your `DbJobType` table, then you should **1)** change your database query to actually only select that column and **2)** utilize the [`Result.scalars`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalars) method to return just a list of strings.

Here is how that would look:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select

# ... import DbJobType


def search_job_types(search_word: str, db: Session) -> list[str]:
    ...
    statement = select(DbJobType.name).filter()  # add your filter options here
    result = db.execute(statement)
    return result.scalars().all()
```

Technically, you also don't need to specify a `response_model` for the route. If you omit that argument, it will still work. Since there is no additional parsing to be done, a proper return type annotation of `list[str]` will be enough to generate the correct OpenAPI schema for that route.

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

# ... import search_job_types


app = FastAPI()
...

@app.get("/search-job-types")
def job_types(search_word: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> list[str]:
    return search_job_types(search_word, db)
```

It seems as though, at least for this route, your `JobTypeDisplay` model is obsolete.

Comment: thanks for idea, just small issue AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'scalars'

Comment: @TomasAm `Query` is legacy code and you should probably move away from using it. That is why I used [`Session.execute`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.execute) to get a [`Result`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result) object. It has the `scalars` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to `return_model=list[str]` and change your return statement to

```py
return [jt.name for jt in all]
```

Comment: While this would certainly result in the correct output, a list comprehension is still a loop. OP is right in his attempt to avoid loops in Python as much as possible.